# Unable to get database credentials from AWS parameter store in time to make DB connection after Spring Boot upgrade to 2.7.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-connection, aws-parameter-store

I recently upgraded a Spring Boot microservice from v2.6.7 to v2.7.2.  In the code, we retrieve database credentials from an AWS parameter store and use them to connect to a Postgres database.   We take param values that indicate what to retrieve from the AWS parameter store, retrieve those values and and then add those values to the Spring environment (as spring.datasource.username & spring.datasource.password).

This was working without issue before we upgraded to 2.7.2.  However, since the upgrade, we seem to have a timing issue where a database connection is attempted before the values have been retrieved. We don't even reach the code to do the parameter store retrieval before it tries to make the DB connection. However, in my properties file, if I put valid values in the hardcoded parameters below (& uncomment them), the database connection is made and I see the code to go get the AWS parameter store values run, so I know the code is good. The class that does the work of getting the values is @Autowired in my SpringBootApplication class.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<aws URL>
spring.datasource.username.param=<aws parameter store for username>
spring.datasource.password.param=<aws parameter store for password>
# spring.datasource.username=<a valid hardcoded username>
# spring.datasource.password=<a valid hardcoded pwd>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.301</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Did anything change in the latest Spring Boot version that would affect the nature &/or order of the auto wiring? How can I force the database connection attempt to wait until the DB creds have been retrieved? Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: How _specifically_ are you "retrieving values from AWS Parameter Store"? Spring Cloud Config? Custom code—exposing the values via what API(s)?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- We're using an AWS library - dependency added to problem description (com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.*), specifically com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.GetParameterRequest & com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.GetParameterResult to get the values after a connection to our AWS instance via com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.

Comment: So you have a custom implementation that uses the AWS SDK v1? How is this integrated into your Spring Context? Does it implement `PropertyResolver`?

Comment: Thanks chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- for your help/questions!  We aren't using PropertyResolver but def open to any suggestions there. 

@Autowired
public void setProtectedProperties(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
 Properties protectedProperties = new Properties();
 /* Logic to retrieve & then put name/value pairs for 
  spring.datasource.username & spring.datasource.password in protectedProperties
  protectedProperties.put(name, protectedValue);
 */
 env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("protected-service-props", protectedProperties));
}

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem.
Paramter store values are beeing retrieved after DataSource initiation with autoconfiguration done by boot from properties file.

Solution in my case was creation of custom DataSource (wrapped in javax.sql interface) and use `@DependsOn("ParameterStorePropertySource")` on Bean creation,
this forces my ParameterStore bean and custom PropertySource i created to be initiated before DataSource

```
public class AwsParameterStorePropertySource extends PropertySource<AWSSimpleSystemsManagement> {
      //    private static final String activeProfile = System.getenv("spring_profiles_active");

    public AwsParameterStorePropertySource(String name, AWSSimpleSystemsManagement source) {

        super(name, source);
    }

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String parameter) {
        if (parameter.startsWith("/ssm")) {
            try {
                GetParameterRequest parameterRequest = new GetParameterRequest();
               //                parameterRequest.withName(activeProfile + "-" + parameter);
                var parameterNameWithoutPrefix = parameter.substring(4);
                parameterRequest.withName(parameterNameWithoutPrefix);
                GetParameterResult parameterResult = source.getParameter(parameterRequest);

                return parameterResult.getParameter().getValue();
            } catch (ParameterNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

then Config file for spring to use this class, just to make sure i added `@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` bean creation order

```
@Configuration(value = "ParameterStorePropertySource")
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AwsParameterStorePropertySourceConfig {
    private final AWSSimpleSystemsManagement simpleSystemsManagement;
    private final ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    public AwsParameterStorePropertySourceConfig(AWSSimpleSystemsManagement simpleSystemsManagement,
                                                 ConfigurableEnvironment env) {

        this.env = env;
        this.simpleSystemsManagement = simpleSystemsManagement;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        AwsParameterStorePropertySource propertySource = new AwsParameterStorePropertySource("ParameterStorePropertySource", simpleSystemsManagement);
        env.getPropertySources().addFirst(propertySource);
    }
}
```

And finally DataSource config file

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Value("${mysql_url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${mysql_user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${mysql_pw}")
    private String pw;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("ParameterStorePropertySource")
    public DataSource getMySqlDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                .url("jdbc:mysql:"+url)
                .username(user)
                .password(pw)
                .build();
    }
}
```

After this My db was intiated with injected parameter store values. Also you can use commented section to use it with profiles, i am currently working with only one profile so i did not need this code. You can also pass profile to SSMClient creation  for customazation

```
@Configuration
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleSystemManagementConfig {
    @Bean
    public AWSSimpleSystemsManagement simpleSystemsManagement() {
//        if (activeProfile.equals("dev")) {
//            return AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard()
//                    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder
//                            .EndpointConfiguration("http://localstack.host:4583", awsRegion))
//                    .build();
//        } else {
        return AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard().
                withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()).build();
//        }
    }
}
```

Hope this was usefull to someone.

PS. Environment:
`SpringBoot 2.6.7`
`spring-cloud 2021.0.5`
`Java 17`